How to ensure canvas stays centered and fully visible within its parent element when zooming in React?
I am working on a simple PowerPoint maker using React, where I have implemented a zoom function for a canvas element. The canvas is supposed to resize based on a scale factor. However, when the canvas goes outside of its parent element, the left and top sides of the canvas are not visible even when scrolling. Only the right and bottom edges are visible with scrolling.
Demo Here

The issue you're encountering is related to the way the scaling and scrolling behavior is handled in your React component. When the canvas element scales up, it extends beyond the boundaries of its parent container, but only the bottom and right edges are scrollable, not the left and top edges. This happens because of how the CSS overflow and scaling are managed.
To resolve this issue, you can make the following adjustments:
Ensure the parent container's size is fixed or properly managed to allow scrolling in all directions.
Position the canvas correctly within the parent container to ensure it stays centered even when scaled.
Adjust the overflow settings to handle the scaled canvas properly.
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const parentRef = useRef(null);
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = 800 * scale;
    canvas.height = 450 * scale;

    canvas.style.width = `${800 * scale}px`;
    canvas.style.height = `${450 * scale}px`;

    draw(ctx, scale);
  }, [scale]);

  const draw = (context, scale) => {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    context.save();
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(100 * scale, 100 * scale, 200 * scale, 100 * scale);
    context.restore();
  };

  const onZoom = (add) => {
    setScale((prev) => prev + add);
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={parentRef}
      style={{
        // height: "100vh",
        // width: "100vw",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "column",
        // overflow: "auto",
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          height: "100vh",
          width: "100vw",
          overflow: "scroll",
        }}
      >
        <canvas
          ref={canvasRef}
          style={{ border: "2px solid red" }}
          width={800}
          height={450}
        >
          Drawing canvas
        </canvas>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => onZoom(0.1)}>+</button>
        <button onClick={() => onZoom(-0.1)}>-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


